# Populating multiple drop-down menus with static values

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

This is a relatively straightforward task I'd like to accomplish without jquery or AJAX.

I have a couple javascript arrays A and B, and I have multiple rows in an HTML form that each contain two columns containing dropdowns which will each contain the contents of A and B. I'd like to populate every dropdown of a certain name with a predefined set of items. This can be done after the page has already loaded.

Any ideas as to what the javascript would look like? How can I address a slew of items named one thing?

Comment: You want to fill each select matching a given name with the values in multiple arrays? Is that what I'm reading?

Comment: static != javascript. What am I missing here/

Comment: Both answers seem on the money, I'll get to finishing up my testcase tomorrow. By "static" I meant to draw a distinction from the question I came upon quite a bit on searching for an answer to this one: "how do I make dropdowns alter other dropdowns dynamically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for one of your arrays:

```
// String values; can be used as name, id, or innerHTML 
var valsA = ['one','two','three'];
// Variable to store <option> object
var opt;

// Loop through vals and make an <option> for each one
for(var i=0;i<valsA.length;i++) {
  // Create node
  opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
  // Set innerHTML, if you want
  opt.innerHTML = valsA[i];
  // Set the names to be all the same, if you want
  opt.setAttribute("name","oneThing");
  // Set unique ID, somehow, if you want
  opt.id = "value"+i+valsA[i];
  // Finally, append <option> to dropdown menu
  document.getElementById('myDropdown').appendChild(opt);
}
```

Your HTML should have a `<select id='myDropdown'></select>` ready to go before this script is run.  You can do the same process for the other array.

Also, keep in mind that names

- are not necessarily unique
- can be used to get groups of items

while IDs

- should be unique
- unfortunately your script will run if they're not, this can be a source of errors
- should be used to get a single object

So, make sure each of your dropdowns has a unique ID so your script can find it correctly.

Comment: I think you may want to increment `i`, not `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML lookes like this:

```
<body>
  <select id="fillme" name="fillme"></select>
  <select id="fillme" name="fillme"></select>
  <select id="fillme" name="fillme"></select>
  <select id="fillme" name="fillme"></select>
</body>
```

And you just want to fill in the values from multiple arrays:

```
var a = ['one','two','three'];
var b = ['four', 'five'];
```

You can concatenate the arrays and use getElementsByName (as long as the selects have ids matching the names too, IE needs that).

```
var values = a.concat(b);
var selects = document.getElementsByName('fillme');

var i = selects.length;
while (i--) {
  var select = selects[i];
  for (var j=0,length=values.length; j<length; j++) {
      select.add(new Option(values[j]));
  }
}​
```

**JSBin Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ehoni4/2